# Burn: the Repair Button

Tags: wix, wix3.6, burn

I have some problems understanding how the 'repair button' works in burn.
If my program is installed, and I'll click the repair button, my program is beeing installed again (if I understood the log files right).
Is there a way to controll what's happening by clicking the button?? For example that it should redirect me to the .msi modify/change interface?

Am I right, that this line in the Rtf-theme:

> < Button Name="RepairButton" X="-171" Y="-11" Width="75" Height="23" TabStop="yes" FontId="0" HideWhenDisabled="yes">#(loc.ModifyRepairButton) < /Button >

the *loc.ModifyRepairButton* redirects me to somewhere else??

This is what I would like to achieve:

The user should have the possibility to add some packages after the installation, for example if he has forgotten to check somehting or some hardware has changed etc.

thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard WiX UI doesn't appear to offer the user the ability modify installation options seleted during the initial installation, only to either uninstall completely or repair the installation.

If you want to have Burn allow you to modify the installation then I believe the only solution (at least for now) will be to create your own custom UI for Burn, e.g. by using the [managed bootstrapper application host](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/heaths/archive/2011/10/28/introducing-managed-bootstrapper-applications.aspx), and have that UI invoke the modify action on the bootstrapper engine (which will in turn invoke the modify action on your MSI).

The `#(loc.ModifyRepairButton)` is just the text to be displayed for the button - this syntax instructs Burn to look up the value of the `ModifyRepairButton` entry in the .wxl file.  its the `Name` of the button which defines the behaviour of the button, however unfortunately there doesn't appear to be a corresponding "ModifyButton" behaviour defined in the standard boostrapper UI.